# How to move View Controllers on the Storyboard?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

How can I arrange View Controllers on a Storyboard in Xcode's Interface Builder? When I try to select a View Controller, the mouse pointer grabs a view inside it instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it wasn't obvious, at least for me. You should **drag the white bar** above the View Controller (the bar that contains the First Responder). It works even on low zoom levels!
[image: Xcode Screenshot: moving a View Controller]